# Magento Admin panel broke suddenly 1.9.x.x

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-community

I logged into to Magento's Admin panel to find it is broken. All the tabs & sub-tabs are appearing in distorted way. I'm attaching screenshot below. How this happened suddenly? Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Front side working or not ? only back end issue ?

Comment: remove cache folder from magento and then try.

Comment: @SHPatel : Only backend issue. Working fine on frontend.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - Already tried that plenty of times. Posted this questions after I got tired of clearing caches :)

Comment: Check console it show missing css, you can copy that css file from default magento of same version which you used.

Comment: @MohitSingh, please check once and change the base secure and unsecure url s at web

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring files from adminhtml and admin css from your version you have.

Provide more information about last patches, modules, changes you made.

Comment: I didn't add extra module than Nitrogento. I uninstalled it after this error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old - sorry to not get here sooner :).

I ran into exactly this problem (from what the screenshot tells me). Couldn't find a solution anywhere. Finally realized a row had been added to core_config_data which didn't have a path. This seems to kill the Magento admin good.